HIghlight in red incorrect digits of Pi in a string
I am trying to test each character in Pi_Entered to Pi, if wrong then highlight vbRed and move the next character. I get TTFTTTTF instead of digits. Highlight in red incorrect digits of Pi in a string. not sure what I am doing wrong.
Sub Highlight_Error_Digits()
    '
    ' After entering the digits, press the "Show Error Digits" highlighted in Red
    '
    Dim X, Pi_Str_Len As Integer
    Dim Pi_String, Pi_Entrd_String As String
    
    Pi_String = Range("$C$7")
    Pi_Entrd_String = Range("$C$6")
    Pi_Str_Len = Len(Pi_String)
    
    '
    Worksheets("Pi_Key'd_In").Activate
    For X = 1 To Pi_Str_Len
        If Mid(Pi_Entrd_String, X, 1) <> Mid(Pi_String, X, 1) Then
            Worksheets("Pi_Key'd_In").Activate
            Range("C9").Activate
            ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=Mid(Pi_Entrd_String, X, 1), Length:=1).Font.Color = vbRed
        Else
            Worksheets("Pi_Key'd_In").Activate
            Range("C9").Activate
            ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=Mid(Pi_Entrd_String, X, 1), Length:=1).Font.Color = vbBlack
        End If
    Next X
    Range("$C$9").Value = Pi_Entrd_String
End Sub


Try this code:
Sub Highlight_Error_Digits()
    '
    ' After entering the digits, press the "Show Error Digits" highlighted in Red
    '
    Dim X As Integer, Pi_Str_Len As Integer
    Dim Pi_String As String, Pi_Entrd_String As String
    
    Pi_String = Range("$C$7").Text     ' Value
    Pi_Entrd_String = Range("$C$6").Value
    Pi_Str_Len = Len(Pi_Entrd_String)
    
    '
    Worksheets(1).Activate   ' Worksheets("Pi_Key'd_In")
    Range("$C$9").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("$C$9").Value = Pi_Entrd_String
    Range("C9").Activate
    For X = 1 To Pi_Str_Len
        If Mid(Pi_Entrd_String, X, 1) <> Mid(Pi_String, X, 1) Then
            ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=X, Length:=1).Font.Color = vbRed
        Else
            ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=X, Length:=1).Font.Color = vbBlack
        End If
    Next X
    
End Sub



Compare Two Strings and Highlight Wrong Characters

Sub HighlightWrongPiDigits()
    
    Const COLOR_CORRECT As Long = vbBlack
    Const COLOR_WRONG As Long = vbRed
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Pi_Key'd_In")
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = ws.Range("C9")
    
    Dim PiCorrect As String: PiCorrect = CStr(ws.Range("C7").Value)
    Dim PiEntered As String: PiEntered = CStr(ws.Range("C6").Value)
    
    cell.ClearContents
    cell.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    
    Dim PiLength As Long: PiLength = Len(PiCorrect)
    If PiLength > Len(PiEntered) Then PiLength = Len(PiEntered)
    
    Dim p As Long, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    For p = 1 To PiLength
        ' Highlight all characters wrong (only once). Why not before?
        ' 1.) If there are no chars, the cell format remains as is.
        ' 2.) If more chars are entered, the surplus will already be
        '     formatted incorrectly.
        If Not IsFirstFound Then
            cell.Value = "'" & PiEntered ' copy as a string
            cell.Font.Color = COLOR_WRONG
            IsFirstFound = True ' never reset
        End If
        ' Highlight matching characters correctly.
        If Mid(PiEntered, p, 1) = Mid(PiCorrect, p, 1) Then
            cell.Characters(Start:=p, Length:=1).Font.Color = COLOR_CORRECT
        End If
    Next p

End Sub


One more:
Sub Highlight_Error_Digits()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, minLen As Long, i As Long, c As Range, clr As Long
    Dim Pi_String As String, Pi_Entrd_String As String 'every variable needs a type
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pi_Key'd_In")
    Pi_String = ws.Range("C7").Value
    Pi_Entrd_String = ws.Range("C6").Value
    minLen = Application.Min(Len(Pi_String), Len(Pi_Entrd_String))
    
    Set c = ws.Range("C9")
    c.NumberFormat = "@" 'set format to "Text"
    c.Font.Color = vbBlack 'reset cell font
    c.Value = Pi_Entrd_String
    For i = 1 To minLen
        clr = IIf(Mid(Pi_String, i, 1) = Mid(Pi_Entrd_String, i, 1), vbGreen, vbRed) 'Color?
        c.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = clr
    Next i
End Sub

